# Is there a way to set Chrome extension settings using selenium?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome-extension, webdriver

I am able to place extension using crx file. However, I need to change some setting in Chrome extension using selenium. Is there any chrome API or somehow I can automate this part. Appreciate!

Comment: what kind of Extension setting ?

Answer (score -1):

When you instantiate the ChromeDriver, try using the below code:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addExtensions(new File("/path/to/extension.crx"));
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: above code I have but I can't access extension settings. I need to switch on few option from the extension.

Comment: @raj Can you add some sample code snap? Actually what you have tried?

Comment: //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/Documents/chromedriver");
 driver = new ChromeDriver();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addExtensions(new File("Switch.crx"));
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
driver = new ChromeDriver(caps);
LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
logPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);}  I want to capture all log after turning exntion settings on.